# How to get unique values from faker?

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-8, laravel-factory

I would like to ask how to generate unique value from faker?

I know this is a familiar question actually, you may put some duplicate links e.g. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202886/laravel-seeding-multiple-unique-columns-with-faker), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986143/how-with-faker-word-get-unique-value) but unfortunately, these links does not answer my problem.

---

Here is my code below. I tried `unique(true)` but same result.

```
return [
    'user_id' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 10),
    //more code here
];
```

Below is the result that I got. As you can see there are lots of duplicate "5" inserted.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Laravel, how do I retrieve a random user\_id from the Users table for Model Factory seeding data generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102483/in-laravel-how-do-i-retrieve-a-random-user-id-from-the-users-table-for-model-fa)

Comment: @KamleshPaul it did not returned **unique** values, no difference from my code above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *factory* is the real issue here not the *faker*. Calling of *factory* I mean.

Let's say you have `User` and `User_Information` model for example since you have not mention any models in your question above.

---

I assume you call the *factory* like below in which it creates a model one by one separately up to **10** that makes `unique()` of `faker` useless.

```
\App\Models\User_Information::factory()->create(10);
```

My **solution** to this problem is to use a *loop* to make `unique()` functional.

```
$max = 10;
for($c=1; $c<=$max; $c++) {
    \App\Models\User_Information::factory()->create();
}
```

> NOTE: `$max` must not be greater to `User::count()`, else it will return an `OverflowException` error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a setup like this

```php
class DomainFactory extends Factory {
    protected $model = Domain::class;

    public function definition() {
       return ['name' => $this->faker->unique()->domainWord()]
    }
}
```

```php
// Seeder
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $domain = Domain::factory()->create();
    ...
}
```

Which did NOT generate unique values for `name` because I basically create a new factory and with that a new faker in each loop run. I had to pull the factory out of the loop:

```php
// Seeder
$factory = Domain::factory();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $domain = $factory->create();
    ...
}
```