# Child table seeding for an incremental column in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-seeder

`stores` table (`id`, `name`)

`store_opening_hours` table (`id`, `store_id`, `day_of_week`, `opens_at`, `closes_at`)

`StoreFactory.php` file:

```
class StoreFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => fake()->company
        ];
    }
}
```

`StoreOpeningHourFactory.php` file:

```
class StoreOpeningHourFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'store_id' => Store::factory(),
            'day_of_week' => // What to put here?,
            'opens_at' => fake()->time('H:i'),
            'closes_at' => fake()->time('H:i'),
        ];
    }
}
```

`StoreSeeder.php` file:

```
class StoreSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        Store::factory()
            ->has(StoreOpeningHour::factory()->count(7))
            ->create(10);
    }
}
```

The `day_of_week` will always be incrementing from `[0-6]` for each store. How to do that inside `StoreOpeningHourFactory.php` file?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I am solving it like this:

```
class StoreOpeningHourFactory extends Factory
{
    private static int $dayOfWeek = 0;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'store_id' => Store::factory(),
            'day_of_week' => static::$dayOfWeek++ % 7,
            'opens_at' => fake()->time('H:i'),
            'closes_at' => fake()->time('H:i'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use

```
$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(0, 6)
```

But you can add only 7 rows, will also be awesome to store week_of_the_year
so you have unique on 2 columns

You also have some notes there
[How to get unique values from faker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220203/how-to-get-unique-values-from-faker)

Another implementation, you can use **afterMaking** callback, add an array of possible values and delete a random value from it, when array is empty get the default array

```
 public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterMaking(function (StoreOpeningHour $storeOpeningHour) {
             $this->definition['day_of_week'] = #random_value_from_one_to_six#

        });
    }
```

Comment: The `week_of_the_year` is not relevant here, since I am just storing the opening hours of each store. I would like to follow the sequence. Let's say for `store:1`, there'll be `7` entries in `store_opening_hours` table where `day_of_week` will be incrementing like `0-6`.